# Can uploading public_html folder to another hosting service provider not be enough if the database wasn't backed up?

Tags: wordpress, backup

I had downloaded the whole public_html folder of wordpress of my website before moving to a new hosting provider. Meanwhile the old hosting is no longer available now. I was not aware that for the database one needs separate backup.

So does it mean that I can not have the full old website back if I only backedup the public_html folder? 
Also can I still get something useful out of the public_html folder by uploading it to the new hosting or do I have to have a full start from scratch?

Comment: If your site is a normal WordPress site you essentially have lost everything. However, the old hosting provider almost certainly has a backup of your database. If you are not currently a customer they may not want to help you but you can very politely ask them for a dump of your old database. I don't know how much work you will lose but if is really a lot you can ask them if you became a customer again will they restore your old site. In hindsight it is not a good idea to delete the old before the new is working - personally, I have learned that lesson the hard way multiple times. Good luck.

Comment: I should point out that attachments - images, video, audio ... are stored directly in the public_html folder so you at least have that to work with if you want to rebuild your site from scratch.

Comment: Maybe you're lucky and it is cached on Google, put this on Chrome URL: `cache:http://YOUR_SITE.com` or on the Web Archive: `https://web.archive.org/web/*/YOUR_SITE.com`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress stores all the text of your posts in the database, which also includes metadata about theme and plugin settings, etc. Theme files, plugin files, post images and other uploaded files are stored in the `wp-content` folder so you are good. You should backup your database before you migrate.

That said, you might be able to retrieve the text from the Internet Archive (https://archive.org/) if you are lucky. But that means you have to somehow manually get the posts back to the new database.

Answer (score 0):

All your WordPress pages are stored in the database. If your database is gone or absent, I recommend you start all over. In your current situation, you can recover your theme.

It is also possible that the theme does not function properly if some of its setting where registered in the database.